# Arrays of schema types on Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema:

```
var s = new Schema({
  links: {
    type: [Url]
  }
});
```

In this case I am using the url schema type from https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-types - but I have tried this with other types. Mongoose doesn't seem to validate/use the schema type when in an array - works fine without the array.

How can I define an array of schema types that will validate?

Comment: Seems that it will only work with built in types. Doesn't look like I can inject the new type in the check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer from Mongoose creator:

"Unless the Url is a subdocument, validation will not get triggered currently (there is a ticket open somewhere to support richer types). The work-around is to define validation on the array: https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/12f9ad103e0378db6afc"

I ended up creating subdocuments as Mongoose supports validation on them when in array form.

```
var links = new Schema({
  link: URL
});

var s = new Schema({
  links: {
   type: [links]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `var s = new Schema({links: [Url]});`