# Define an array of objects, each object is a predefined schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas: Category, and User

**Category** schema is defined as follows:

```
title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Title field is required'],
    unique: true
},
type: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Type field is required'],
}
```

**User** schema

```
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    select: false,
},
categories: [{ /* Category schema object */}],
```

What I'm trying to implement is when ever a user registers, the categories array must be required, and each object within it must match and follow the predefined *category* schema and have an objectID.

How to do that with Mongoose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrays of schema types on Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047520/arrays-of-schema-types-on-mongoose). There are multiple ways to do it, the most concise is `categories: [Category]`. Please refer to mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Import the Category schema into the file where you have defined the User schema, then simply specify the type as array, like this:

```js
const Category = require(....);
.
.
.
.
categories: [{
   type: Category,
   ref: "Category"
]
```

Comment: If `type` is `Category`, `ref` should probably be `"Category"` not `"User"`

Comment: thanks, it similar to the logic I tried before and I was getting  this error: 
Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `categories`

Comment: @MohamedShublaq you should put what's returned from `new Schema(...)` (probably `CategorySchema`) not what's returned from `mongoose.model(...)`

Comment: @TheeSritabtim Nice! that was the mistake actually, I defined it as
`categories: [{ type: category, required: true }]`
but the validation is not running at all if I'm passing an empty array, any ideas?

Comment: @MohamedShublaq so you want an array to be required and not empty? Have you tried `categores: { type: [category], ref: 'Category', required: true }` ?